# Play Framework app constantly throws a null pointer on line 6

Tags: java, playframework, nullpointerexception, persistence, ebean

I'm trying to make a simple forum system in Play Framework, but I'm getting an error in a strange way. I have a `forum.java` class which is the source of the error, but regardless of the code inside, it always throws a null pointer on line 6. Here's as much as is relevant, I think.

```
package models;

import io.ebean.Finder;
import io.ebean.Model;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class Forum extends Model {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Thread> threads;
```

The offending line is the `javax.persistence.CascadeType` import, but I've already removed it, shifted it downwards, remade the class. Regardless, the error continues to throw on line 6. It doesn't explain what's causing the null pointer, either. It even throws when the line is empty.

[image]

For reference, I have plenty of other classes that are laid out in the same format. I've tried to clean the project in the sbt console and I've tried remaking the class from the ground up. I'm sure it's some kind of fundamental error, but I have no idea where to even start.

Edit: Stacktrace added

```
[info] play.api.Play - Application started (Dev)
[error] application -

! @77hm04h99 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/forum/1] ->

play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[NullPointerException: null]]
        at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:255)
        at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:182)
        at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(AkkaHttpServer.scala:320)
        at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(AkkaHttpServer.scala:318)
        at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$recoverWith$1(Future.scala:414)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transformWith$1(Promise.scala:37)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanPropertyAssocMany.createReference(BeanPropertyAssocMany.java:652)
        at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptor.lazyLoadMany(BeanDescriptor.java:2082)
        at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptor.lazyLoadMany(BeanDescriptor.java:2071)
        at io.ebeaninternal.server.loadcontext.DLoadBeanContext$LoadBuffer.loadBean(DLoadBeanContext.java:172)
        at io.ebean.bean.EntityBeanIntercept.loadBeanInternal(EntityBeanIntercept.java:812)
        at io.ebean.bean.EntityBeanIntercept.loadBean(EntityBeanIntercept.java:785)
        at io.ebean.bean.EntityBeanIntercept.preGetter(EntityBeanIntercept.java:885)
        at models.Forum._ebean_get_threads(Forum.java:6)
        at models.Forum.getThreads(Forum.java:37)
        at views.html.forum$.apply(forum.template.scala:41)
```

Stacktrace v2 :

```
[error] application -

! @77hpce3hh - Internal server error, for (GET) [/forum/1] ->

play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[PersistenceException: Query threw SQLException:Column "T1.FORUM_ID" not found; SQL statement:
select t0.id, t1.id, t1.title, t1.replies, t1.last_reply, t1.forum_id from forum t0 left join thread t1 on t1.forum_id = t0.id  where t0.id = ?   order by t0.id [42122-196] Bind values:[null] Query was:select t0.id, t1.id, t1.title, t1.replies, t1.last_reply, t1.forum_id from forum t0 left join thread t1 on t1.forum_id = t0.id  where t0.id = ?   order by t0.id]]
        at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:255)
        at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:182)
        at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(AkkaHttpServer.scala:320)
        at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(AkkaHttpServer.scala:318)
        at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$recoverWith$1(Future.scala:414)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transformWith$1(Promise.scala:37)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Query threw SQLException:Column "T1.FORUM_ID" not found; SQL statement:
select t0.id, t1.id, t1.title, t1.replies, t1.last_reply, t1.forum_id from forum t0 left join thread t1 on t1.forum_id = t0.id  where t0.id = ?   order by t0.id [42122-196] Bind values:[null] Query was:select t0.id, t1.id, t1.title, t1.replies, t1.last_reply, t1.forum_id from forum t0 left join thread t1 on t1.forum_id = t0.id  where t0.id = ?   order by t0.id
        at io.ebean.config.dbplatform.SqlCodeTranslator.translate(SqlCodeTranslator.java:48)
        at io.ebean.config.dbplatform.DatabasePlatform.translate(DatabasePlatform.java:195)
        at io.ebeaninternal.server.query.CQueryEngine.translate(CQueryEngine.java:139)
        at io.ebeaninternal.server.query.DefaultOrmQueryEngine.translate(DefaultOrmQueryEngine.java:38)
        at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.OrmQueryRequest.translate(OrmQueryRequest.java:81)
        at io.ebeaninternal.server.query.CQuery.createPersistenceException(CQuery.java:666)
        at io.ebeaninternal.server.query.CQueryEngine.find(CQueryEngine.java:422)
        at io.ebeaninternal.server.query.DefaultOrmQueryEngine.findId(DefaultOrmQueryEngine.java:162)
        at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.OrmQueryRequest.findId(OrmQueryRequest.java:327)
        at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.findId(DefaultServer.java:1175)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "T1.FORUM_ID" not found; SQL statement:
select t0.id, t1.id, t1.title, t1.replies, t1.last_reply, t1.forum_id from forum t0 left join thread t1 on t1.forum_id = t0.id  where t0.id = ?   order by t0.id [42122-196]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
        at org.h2.expression.ExpressionColumn.optimize(ExpressionColumn.java:147)
        at org.h2.command.dml.Select.prepare(Select.java:839)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:263)
        at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:578)
        at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:519)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1204)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:73)
```

Comment: Run the `clean` command, your classes might not be up-to-date.

Comment: I've tried, unfortunately. Usually it's my go-to fix for strange stuff like this, but it doesn't seem to work. I'll pass ask someone else in my group to try running it and see if it's a problem with my environment

Comment: Can you include the full stackTrace in your question?

Comment: Right. Added it into the question. For context, the time this occurs is when I'm loading up a forum page. I've got a range of subforums and whenever I click to enter one, it should identify which forum to load on the forum view, then get the list of threads that have been posted there.

Comment: `at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanPropertyAssocMany` makes me think that you defined a `ManyToOne`, `OneToMany` or `ManyToMany` wrong. You might want to check that.

Comment: Also, did you check what was at `models.Forum.getThreads(Forum.java:37)` ? The nullPointer could come from here too.

Comment: I've checked over the relationships and they all seem to be fine. Going over Ebean documentation, it seems like they're all mapped the right way, and changing them doesn't seem to change the error. Also, on the topic of the thread getter, it's just like a default getter. Returns a list of threads. I've tried implementing a check in the forum view to display an error message if the list of threads on the forum is empty, which seems to work well enough.

Comment: Can you share the `getThreads` function ? and tell me which line is the  37th ?

Comment: ` public List<Thread> getThreads() { return threads; } ` The 37th line is the return statement, and the list that's being returned is in the ` forum.java ` code above

Comment: Your `ManyToOne` annotation seems wrong to me here. You have *one* forum for *many* threads. So it should be `OneToMany` instead.

Comment: Ebean's documentation says that ManyToOne is the mapping for the 'one' side, which would be forum in this case, but their documentation has been off many times before, so I guess that might just be flat-out wrong. Regardless, swapping the mappings around has changed the error. I'm not sure if I should add it onto the question as it'd be a bit too long in that case, but it's there for now. It's too late now to take a long, hard look into this but I'll take another crack at it in the morning

Comment: Alright, keep me updated.

Comment: After much tinkering, I think you were actually spot on about the mappings. The forum works now and it's with the exact opposite type of mappings that the Ebean documentation specified. I think there was an error with the ManyToOne and OneToMany mapping between forum.java and thread.java. I changed both of their mappings, so that Thread has the ManyToOne mapping and Forum has the OneToMany, despite Ebean saying that ManyToOne was for the 'one' side. The forum seems to work now, thanks bunches. I'd select your answer but this is just a comment. If you could turn it into an answer that'd be fine

Comment: I'll summarize it all to an answer in a few.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanPropertyAssocMany.createReference(BeanPropertyAssocMany.java:652)
```

Can help you understand what went wrong here:

You have misused the `@ManyToOne` annotation.

In your application, you have **one** `Forum` for **many** `Threads`, so the annotation above the list of `Threads` inside your `Forum` Model should be

```
@OneToMany
```

You also need to switch the annotation above the declaration of `Forum` in your `Thread` Model to

```
@ManyToOne
```

Answer (score 1):

Note to those that came here googling for this NullPointerException: the exact same issue can also happen when forgetting to add the @DbArray tag to a field.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Gerardo who really cares though